# Find the IP of the router between me and main router/gateway?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have a Netgear router that is the main router/gateway in and out of the network. Then I have a Linksys 54g router with WiFi that we use as are main WiFi access point

The Cat5 runs from the router to the WiFi routers LAN port (not WAN). And then if you connect to that WAP you are basically on the network.

I want to be able to find out what the IP address of that WAP is but so far I can't figure out how to:

- I've tried doing a **tracert** to the gateway IP but I get nothing.
- I've scanned all the IP addressed in the network.
- I've gone to the Netgear main router and looked under attached devices but it doesn't say anything.

Any ideas on how I can figure out how to administer it? (I do have limited physical access but my attempt to plug into it came back with a faulty IP (in the 169 range where the rest of the office is 192.168...).

I never set this router up to begin with so I'm reluctant to just kill it with the reset button because I can't get into see what the settings are set to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Angry IP Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home) to see which devices on your subnet are listening on port 80.

Most routers do not show IP addresses for attached devices that are statically assigned, or are not assigned by their DHCP server.

It's also entirely possible that your Wifi is on a different subnet. This wouldn't have caused an issue previously, since your router is doing DHCP. Have you replaced or reset your modem since you had the Wifi put in? If so, try to manually set a computer to an IP address on that subnet, and run Angry again.

Answer (score 2):

First, is your Wifi on another IP subnet than your "main" router? In other words, **does** the AP route between wireless and wired network or does it **bridge** the traffic?

To me it sounds like the latter - your AP is just a bridge between wifi and cable. Therefore, it does not use it's IP in the forwarding process - it's a layer2 device.

If it were a router, you would

1. have a different IP subnet when in wifi than in wired lan (check with `ipconfig`)
2. see the WAP's IP in traceroute

HTH,
PEra

Comment: note the windows traceroute is **tracert**

Comment: yes... in "their world" they have "copy" instead of "cp" but "tracert" instead of "traceroute". weird world :)

Comment: not so much.  remember 8.3 filenames?  traceroute.exe is too long.  :)

Comment: Yeah - they have/had funny limitations everywhere ;)

Answer (score 1):

If as you say, Tracert returns nothing, it pretty much means you are using a bridged gateway type device and without further information of the network, you are not going to find it remotely.

If you have physical access over the network, I would go to the machine that is your gateway, and see how that is set up, then go to that machines gateway and so on... Short of that, I do not think you will find it.